# How to read image in ascending order from folder in matlab and plot as subplot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have multiple image file arranged by name in folder? How can I read the image one by one in ascending order.
Inside folder:

```
B1_L1_11dB_P12_M0.png
B1_L1_11dB_P12_M1.png
B1_L1_11dB_P12_M2.png
B1_L1_11dB_P12_M3.png
B1_L1_11dB_P12_M4.png
B1_L1_11dB_P12_M5.png
B1_L1_11dB_P12_M6.png
B1_L1_11dB_P12_M7.png
```

I want to read the image and plot as subplot subplot(4,2,1)...subplot(4,2,8).

Comment: See: [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) and [loop control statements](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html). SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: also will nead imagesc

Comment: @honi I believe you mean `imread`.

Comment: well also imagesc to plot it

Comment: @honi for single image i am using location=imread('B2_L1.png'); to read and plot it using ax6=subplot(3,2,5)
image(location).

Comment: nothing wrong with that